# duplicates with respect to only that column for every column in the table

Tags: sql

```
col1           col2      col3    col4    col5
9607788997  9607788997    778897    778897  7788997
9607788997  9607788997    778897    778897  7788997
9607788998  9607788997    778894    778897  7788997
9607788999  9607788967    778894    778897  7788997
9607788999  9607788969    778894    778899  778899
```

this is my table. now I need to find only the duplicate among columns and display the duplicates with respect to only that column
and I should get the below table,
 need SQL query. Thanks in advance

```
col1          col2       col3    col4    col5
9607788997   9607788997    778897   778897  7788997
9607788999                 778894
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a code writing service

Comment: which database and version are you using?

Comment: But why do you want to do this? Do 5 separate `SELECT DISTINCT`, one per column.

Comment: here I want to display the duplicated of that corresponding column instead of the entire row. and I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using the ANSI-standard `dense_rank()` function and aggregation:

```
select max(col1) as col1,
       max(col2) as col2,
       max(col3) as col3,
       max(col4) as col4,
       max(col5) as col5 
from ((select col1, null as col2, null as col3, null as col4, null as col5,
              dense_rank() over (order by col1) as seqnum
       from t
       group by col1
      ) union all
      (select null, col2, null as col3, null as col4, null as col5,
              dense_rank() over (order by col2)
       from t
       group by col2
      ) union all
      (select null, null as col2, col3, null as col4, null as col5,
              dense_rank() over (order by col3)
       from t
       group by col3
      ) union all
      (select null, null as col2, null as col3, col4, null as col5,
              dense_rank() over (order by col4)
       from t
       group by col4
      ) union all
      (select null, null as col2, null as col3, null as col4, col5,
              dense_rank() over (order by col5)
       from t
       group by col5
      )
     ) tt
group by seqnum
```